# Get number of times an object is referenced in a ManyToManyField

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many

I have some models that look like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    favorite_books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)

# ...

class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

How can I tell how many times a `Book` has been favorited?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can query the ["through"](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.through) table directly with the ORM:

```
UserProfile.favorite_books.through.objects.filter(book_id=book.id).count()
```

Comment: @mVChr: Ya its one of those kind of hidden properties that end up on the field, that you might not have noticed until you searched :-)

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to replace `appname_*` with the name of the M2M table in your DB, but you can do something like this:

```
from django.db import connections

cursor = connections['default'].cursor()
cursor.execute("""
    SELECT count(*) FROM appname_userprofile_books
    WHERE book_id = {book_id};
""".format(book_id=book_id))
favorited_count_list = cursor.fetchall()
```

You can then pull the number from `favorited_count_list`.